# What is the significance of negative byte values in Java Strings?

Tags: java, string, utf-8

Recently I found some negative bytes hidden in a Java string in my code which was causing a .equals String comparison to fail.

What is the significance of negative byte values in Strings? Can they mean anything? It there any situation in which a negative byte value in a String could be interpreted as anything? I'm noob at this encoding business so if it requires explanation into different encoding schemes please feel free.

Comment: Java bytes are signed.

Comment: What makes you think that it was causing an equals comparison to fail?  More to the point, Java Strings are made out of chars, not bytes.

Comment: When you talk about bytes being in a Java string, what do you mean? Java strings are built of unsigned 16-bit chars.

Comment: Using a CompareTo statement, you can see what the value of a character is.  Something like a space would return a negative number when compared to "a".  Just saying...

Answer (score 2):

A Java string contains characters, BUT you can interpret them in different ways. If each character is a byte, then it can range from 0-255, inclusive.  That's 8 bits.

Now, the leftmost bit can be interpreted as a sign bit or as part of the magnitude of the character. If that bit is interpreted as a sign bit then you will have data items ranging from -128 to +127, inclusive.

You didn't post the code you used to print the characters but if you used logic that interpreted the characters as signed data items then you will get negative numbers in out output.